# Simulating Pointers in Python

Tags: python, pointers

I'm trying to cross compile an in house language(ihl) to Python.

One of the ihl features is pointers and references that behave like you would expect from C or C++.

For instance you can do this:

```
a = [1,2];  // a has an array 
b = &a;     // b points to a
*b = 2;     // derefernce b to store 2 in a
print(a);   // outputs 2
print(*b);   // outputs 2
```

Is there a way to duplicate this functionality in Python.

**I should point out that I think I've confused a few people.  I don't want pointers in Python.  I just wanted to get a sense from the Python experts out there, what Python I should generate to simulate the case I've shown above**

My Python isn't the greatest but so far my exploration hasn't yielded anything promising:(

I should point out that we are looking to move from our ihl to a more common language so we aren't really tied to Python if someone can suggest another language that may be more suitable.

Comment: So you're trying to compile a fairly low-level language to a fairly high-level one?  Have you considered other platforms for your VM instead?

Comment: http://cluecc.sourceforge.net compiles C to various high level languages, but doesn't have a Python backend yet.  It would be interesting to see how it performs, though :)

Comment: One problem with your example is that you are using integers, which in Python is immutable. I.e, you can't change them. This combined with the fact that you have an array variable, which you the overwrite with an integer in your C code (which is horrid from a C perspective) means that you are asking for a way to misuse Python in a way similar to how you misuse C. That just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lennart Regbro.  The language I'm coming from isn't C.  I thought I'd made that clear to you by now:)

Comment: Use size-1 lists for mutable references and non-const pointers: `a=[smth]` `b=[a]` `b[0][0] = 2` `print a[0]` `print b[0][0]`

Comment: @qarma: Why not `b=a`? Writing `b=[a]` seems like overkill since `a` already effectively is a pointer to `smth`.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This can be done explicitly.

```
class ref:
    def __init__(self, obj): self.obj = obj
    def get(self):    return self.obj
    def set(self, obj):      self.obj = obj

a = ref([1, 2])
b = a
print(a.get())  # => [1, 2]
print(b.get())  # => [1, 2]

b.set(2)
print(a.get())  # => 2
print(b.get())  # => 2
```

Comment: You might not want to use the name "ref", since that's the same name as the weakref reference. Perhaps "ptr" or something.  A sensible implementation, though.

Comment: I was thinking of SML, where this is called `'a ref`, but yeah, it would be better to choose a more unique name.  Not sure that `ptr` makes all that much sense, though; it's not actually a pointer, it's more like a single container...

Comment: Note that this is only even meaningful when using immutable objects like ints or strings. For mutable objects a=Something(); b=a; is perfectly enough.

And even with immutable objects it's pretty pointless...

Comment: You can alternately override `__call__` to implement getting and setting, which is more similar to how a weakref behaves.

Comment: I really like this, and it is really similar to Python's builtin [property function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). You could also use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14000962/1020470).

Comment: @ephemient Nice. The whole pointer story is actually one of the things that kept me from going to phyton. How those this look performance whise for a primitive datatype - is there not a lot of overhead? yours magu_

Comment: I don't think this works in the way that it was intended (as others have pointed out).  I assume the goal here is to keep a pointer to another variable but this class keeps track of an object not a variable.  Because of the way most Python names (variables) work, they don't stay attached to the same object or memory location very long.  So this method would soon loose track.  For example.  after an operation such as `i = i + 1`, `i` will point to a new object.

Comment: There is a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 24):

You may want to read [*Semantics of Python variable names from a C++ perspective*](http://rg03.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/semantics-of-python-variable-names-from-a-c-perspective/). The bottom line: **All variables are references**.

More to the point, don't think in terms of variables, but in terms of objects which can be *named*.

Comment: Of course it has variables; a variable in Python is a named object.  Saying "Python doesn't have variables" is just confusing things unnecessarily.

Comment: @Glenn: I take variable to mean a 'named memory location'. Admittedly, that may not be the correct definition. Though this sentence at Wikipedia, if I interpret it correctly, appears to agree with me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28programming%29#In_source_code

Comment: Not if you are thinking of variables as a fixed in memory space, which is what it is in C.

Comment: WP says "an identifier that is linked to a value", which I think describes Python just fine.  (The specific sentence you linked to doesn't contradict this: it says a variable name is one way to get to a memory location, not that the memory location is the variable.)  If you think Python "doesn't have variables", then most other programming languages I've ever used don't, either!  :-)

Comment: Alright, I changed the wording. Hopefully it's now less controversial :)

Answer (score 14):

If you're compiling a C-like language, say:

```
func()
{
    var a = 1;
    var *b = &a;
    *b = 2;
    assert(a == 2);
}
```

into Python, then all of the "everything in Python is a reference" stuff is a misnomer.

It's true that everything in Python is a reference, but the fact that many core types (ints, strings) are immutable effectively undoes this for many cases.  There's no *direct* way to implement the above in Python.

Now, you can do it indirectly: for any immutable type, wrap it in a mutable type.  Ephemient's solution works, but I often just do this:

```
a = [1]
b = a
b[0] = 2
assert a[0] == 2
```

(I've done this to work around Python's lack of "nonlocal" in 2.x a few times.)

This implies a lot more overhead: every immutable type (or every type, if you don't try to distinguish) suddenly creates a list (or another container object), so you're increasing the overhead for variables significantly.  Individually, it's not a lot, but it'll add up when applied to a whole codebase.

You could reduce this by only wrapping immutable types, but then you'll need to keep track of which variables in the output are wrapped and which aren't, so you can access the value with "a" or "a[0]" appropriately.  It'll probably get hairy.

As to whether this is a good idea or not--that depends on why you're doing it.  If you just want something to run a VM, I'd tend to say no.  If you want to be able to call to your existing language from Python, I'd suggest taking your existing VM and creating Python bindings for it, so you can access and call into it from Python.

Comment: Yeah, my `ref` is basically the degenerate 1-element-only case of `list`.  A 1-`tuple` would be lower overhead, but unfortunately those are not mutable.

Comment: By the way, I think what you *really* want is a cell--that's what Python uses to store closures.  Unfortunately, those are an implementation detail that aren't exposed--you can't instantiate them directly.

Answer (score 10):

Almost exactly like [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145848/1020470), which I voted up, you could use Python's builtin [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) function. It will do something nearly similar to the `ref` class in ephemient's answer, except now, instead of being forced to use `get` and `set` methods to access a `ref` instance, you just call the attributes of your instance which you've assigned as *properties* in the class definition. From Python docs (except I changed **C** to **ptr**):

```
class ptr(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None
    def getx(self):
        return self._x
    def setx(self, value):
        self._x = value
    def delx(self):
        del self._x
    x = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")
```

Both methods work like a C pointer, without resorting to `global`. For example if you have a function that takes a pointer:

```
def do_stuff_with_pointer(pointer, property, value):
    setattr(pointer, property, value)
```

For example

```
a_ref = ptr()      # make pointer
a_ref.x = [1, 2]   # a_ref pointer has an array [1, 2]
b_ref = a_ref      # b_ref points to a_ref
# pass ``ptr`` instance to function that changes its content
do_stuff_with_pointer(b_ref, 'x', 3)
print a_ref.x      # outputs 3
print b_ref.x      # outputs 3
```

Another, and totally crazy option would be to use Python's [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html). Try this:

```
from ctypes import *
a = py_object([1,2]) # a has an array 
b = a                # b points to a
b.value = 2          # derefernce b to store 2 in a
print a.value        # outputs 2
print b.value        # outputs 2
```

or if you want to get really fancy

```
from ctypes import *
a = py_object([1,2])   # a has an array 
b = pointer(a)         # b points to a
b.contents.value = 2   # derefernce b to store 2 in a
print a.value          # outputs 2
print b.contents.value # outputs 2
```

which is more like OP's original request. crazy!

Answer (score 4):

Everything in Python is pointers already, but it's called "references" in Python. This is the translation of your code to Python:

```
a = [1,2]  // a has an array 
b = a     // b points to a
a = 2      // store 2 in a.
print(a)   // outputs 2
print(b)  // outputs [1,2]
```

"Dereferencing" makes no sense, as it's *all* references. There isn't anything else, so nothing to dereference to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What is concerning me is the last line of your answer.  For the correct semantics in my old language I'd need be to now print out 2 as in the old language it's a pointer to a.

Comment: That's not a pointer then, but an alias, where you point one name to another name. You can't do that in Python, as that's completely unnecessary. In Python you would simply call it "a" the whole time. No aliases needed.

Answer (score 4):

As others here have said, all Python variables are essentially pointers.

The key to understanding this from a C perspective is to use the unknown by many id() function. It tells you what address the variable points to.

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> id(a)
28354600

>>> b = a
>>> id(a)
28354600

>>> id(b)
28354600
```

Comment: The problem is how to dereference such an address.

Comment: it's still very useful for identifying objects. without this, you'd need to hash the content or explicitly assign an id. in C, pointers are sometimes used to distinguish objects

Comment: "CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory."
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id

Answer (score 1):

This is goofy, but a thought...

```
# Change operations like:
b = &a

# To:
b = "a"

# And change operations like:
*b = 2

# To:
locals()[b] = 2


>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = "a"
>>> locals()[b] = 2
>>> print(a)
2
>>> print(locals()[b])
2
```

But there would be no pointer arithmetic or such, and no telling what other problems you might run into...

Comment: This probably isn't the greatest idea, because changes to locals() aren't guaranteed to be reflected in the environment.

Comment: Also, you can't pass `b` into other functions this way.

Comment: As per Paul's comment - I tested it in a function, and it didn't even change the variable in there.  Can change globals that way in a function, but locals() apparently is just giving a copy of the dict when in a function.

Comment: And still: Why? If you want to reference a, just use a. This is still just trying to make something that is easy in Python, but complicated in C, the complicated C way.

Comment: @Lennart - I don't think anybody would argue its the way to write Python code.  But it seems like what the OP was after was a simple mechanistic way to convert his code to working Python.  And if that is the priority, then maybe finding a way to map pointers and dereferencing onto Python might achieve that goal, admittedly at the cost of resulting hideous - but working - Python code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pointer(object):
    def __init__(self, target=None):
        self.target = target

    _noarg = object()

    def __call__(self, target=_noarg):
        if target is not self._noarg:
            self.target = target
        return self.target
```

```
a = Pointer([1, 2])
b = a

print a() # => [1, 2]
print b() # => [1, 2]

b(2)
print a()  # => 2
print b()  # => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this example is short and clear.

Here we have class with implicit list:

```
class A: 
   foo = []
a, b = A(), A()
a.foo.append(5)
b.foo
ans: [5]
```

Looking at this memory profile (using: `from memory_profiler import profile`), my intuition tells me that this may somehow simulate pointers like in C:

```
Filename: F:/MegaSync/Desktop/python_simulate_pointer_with_class.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     7     31.2 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
     8                             def f():
     9     31.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       a, b = A(), A()
    10                                 #here memoery increase and is coupled
    11     50.3 MiB     19.1 MiB       a.foo.append(np.arange(5000000))
    12     73.2 MiB     22.9 MiB       b.foo.append(np.arange(6000000))
    13     73.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       return a,b


[array([      0,       1,       2, ..., 4999997, 4999998, 4999999]), array([      0,       1,       2, ..., 5999997, 5999998, 5999999])] [array([      0,       1,       2, ..., 4999997, 4999998, 4999999]), array([      0,       1,       2, ..., 5999997, 5999998, 5999999])]
Filename: F:/MegaSync/Desktop/python_simulate_pointer_with_class.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    14     73.4 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    15                             def g():
    16                                 #clearing b.foo list clears a.foo
    17     31.5 MiB    -42.0 MiB       b.foo.clear()
    18     31.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       return a,b


[] []
Filename: F:/MegaSync/Desktop/python_simulate_pointer_with_class.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    19     31.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    20                             def h():
    21                                 #and here mem. coupling is lost ;/
    22     69.6 MiB     38.1 MiB       b.foo=np.arange(10000000)
    23                                 #memory inc. when b.foo is replaced
    24    107.8 MiB     38.1 MiB       a.foo.append(np.arange(10000000))
    25                                 #so its seams that modyfing items of
    26                                 #existing object of variable a.foo,
    27                                 #changes automaticcly items of b.foo
    28                                 #and vice versa,but changing object
    29                                 #a.foo itself splits with b.foo
    30    107.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       return b,a


[array([      0,       1,       2, ..., 9999997, 9999998, 9999999])] [      0       1       2 ..., 9999997 9999998 9999999]
```

And here we have explicit self in class:

```
class A: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.foo = []
a, b = A(), A()
a.foo.append(5)
b.foo
ans: []

Filename: F:/MegaSync/Desktop/python_simulate_pointer_with_class.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    44    107.8 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    45                             def f():
    46    107.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       a, b = B(), B()
    47                                 #here some memory increase
    48                                 #and this mem. is not coupled
    49    126.8 MiB     19.1 MiB       a.foo.append(np.arange(5000000))
    50    149.7 MiB     22.9 MiB       b.foo.append(np.arange(6000000))
    51    149.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       return a,b


[array([      0,       1,       2, ..., 5999997, 5999998, 5999999])] [array([      0,       1,       2, ..., 4999997, 4999998, 4999999])]
Filename: F:/MegaSync/Desktop/python_simulate_pointer_with_class.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    52    111.6 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    53                             def g():
    54                                 #clearing b.foo list
    55                                 #do not clear a.foo
    56     92.5 MiB    -19.1 MiB       b.foo.clear()
    57     92.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       return a,b


[] [array([      0,       1,       2, ..., 5999997, 5999998, 5999999])]
Filename: F:/MegaSync/Desktop/python_simulate_pointer_with_class.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    58     92.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    59                             def h():
    60                                 #and here memory increse again ;/
    61    107.8 MiB     15.3 MiB       b.foo=np.arange(10000000)
    62                                 #memory inc. when b.foo is replaced
    63    145.9 MiB     38.1 MiB       a.foo.append(np.arange(10000000))
    64    145.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       return b,a


[array([      0,       1,       2, ..., 9999997, 9999998, 9999999])] [      0       1       2 ..., 9999997 9999998 9999999]
```

ps: I'm self learning programming (started with Python) so please do not hate me if I'm wrong. Its just mine intuition, that let me think that way, so do not hate me!

Answer (score -1):

```
class A:
    
    _a = 1
    _b = 2

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
    
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value

a = A()

>>> a.a, a.b
(1, 2)

>>> A.b = A.a
>>> a.a, a.b
(1, 1)

>>> a.b = 'b'
>>> a.a, a.b
('b', 'b')

>>> a.a = 'a'
>>> a.a, a.b
('a', 'a')
```

Using only a class will not get the desired results.

```
class A:
    a = 1
    b = 2

>>> A.b = A.a
>>> A.a, A.b
(1, 1)

>>> A.a = 'a'
>>> A.b
1

>>> A.a, A.b
('a', 1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Negative, no pointers.  You should not need them with the way the language is designed.  However, I heard a nasty rumor that you could use the: [ctypes](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/) module to use them.  I haven't used it, but it smells messy to me.

Comment: I know that there are no pointers in Python:)

My goal is to cross compile my existing language into Python so I don't have to support a runtime any longer.

What Python would I generate to simulate my example above?