# Python equivalent of pointers

Tags: python, pointers, reference

In python everything works by reference:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> d = {'a':a}
>>> d['a']
1
>>> a = 2
>>> d['a']
1
```

I want something like this

```
>>> a = 1
>>> d = {'a':magical pointer to a}
>>> d['a']
1
>>> a = 2
>>> d['a']
2
```

What would you substitute for *magical pointer to a* so that python would output what I want.

I would appreciate general solutions (not just for the above dictionary example with independent variables, but something that would work for other collections and class/instance variables)

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145722/simulating-pointers-in-python

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145722/simulating-pointers-in-python

Comment: We call this an "alias".  There are two names for `a`: `a` and `d['a']`.  This is usually considered a bad thing because it's not obvious why something changes.  Why do you want to do this?  What's the point of creating intentionally obscure code?

Comment: @S.Lott, It might be the case where you have multiple large data structures and they point to other large data structure data and you need to modify them in a thread and show in the UI for example.

Answer (score 4):

What about a mutable data structure?

```
>>> a = mutable_structure(1)
>>> d = {'a':a}
>>> d['a']
1
>>> a.setValue(2)
>>> d['a']
2
```

An implementation might look like

```
class mutable_structure:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.val
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution is to just use a list; it's the easiest mutable structure.

```
a = [1]
d = {'a': a}
a[0] = 2
print d['a'][0]
```

Comment: Not a graceful solution, but better than the others and simple. Weird this is not just part of the language in my opinion. I could write an easier to read answer in C than I could in Python for this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is because 1 is a immutable datatype in python, i.e. you can't change the value of it.

To make it work like a pointer, you need a mutable datatype as storage, which you can do yourself with a class definition

```
class Mutable(object):
    pass

a = Mutable()
a.value = 1

d = {'a':a}
a.value = 3
```

`d['a'].value` equals 3 at this point.

If you really want, you can overload operators etc. so that you get the same semantics as for normal integers, but I'd suggest you instead take a look at some functional programming patterns to see why immutable types are nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in a class you could do something like this:

```
class DRefsA(object):
    a = 4

    @property
    def d(self):
        return self.a

    @d.setter
    def d(self, value):
        self.a = value
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit late to the party but heres a solution that works with any data type with lamda

```
a = 1
d = {'a': lambda  : a}
print(d['a']()) #output 1
a = 2
print(d['a']()) #output 2
```