# How to keep variable and dictionary that contains it consistent?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a variable

```
self.foo = 1
```

And a dictionary

```
self.foo_dict = {
    'foo_key' = self.foo
}
```

I would like to be able to change the value of `self.foo` and have it also change in `self.foo_dict`. If this was in C (and the dict was a struct), I'd just use a pointer.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible in Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python equivalent of pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065105/python-equivalent-of-pointers). Instead of using an int as the value of foo, you can make a wrapper class, and use an object of that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for wrapper classes!
Just make `self.foo` a property that accesses the value in your dictionary:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo_):
        self.foo_dict = {}  
        self.foo = foo_

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self.foo_dict["foo_key"]

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self.foo_dict["foo_key"] = value

    def show(self):
        print("foo={} ; foo_dict['foo_key']={}".format(
                        self.foo, self.foo_dict["foo_key"]))

b = Bar(1)
b.show()
b.foo = 2
b.show()
b.foo_dict["foo_key"] = 3
b.show()
```

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/GXAbNl)

Properties look to the outside like normal instance member fields, but they are really custom functions that could do anything. This way the two `foo(...)` methods are called when the `foo` property is accessed. The one decorated with `@property` is the getter and the one decorated with `@PROPERTYNAME.setter` is obviously the setter. You could also restrict read or write access to the property by simply omitting one of the property methods.

Here, they redirect all actions to the dictionary. That way you have exactly one instance of a simple mutable variable, but multiple ways to access it.

The example above would result in this output:

```
foo=1 ; foo_dict['foo_key']=1
foo=2 ; foo_dict['foo_key']=2
foo=3 ; foo_dict['foo_key']=3
```

So as we can see, no matter whether we change the value in the dictionary or through the property, both names always point to the same variable.

Comment: +1 for the property approach. I too wanted to do this just after I posted my first answer. However, your first sentence make me feel... a little nervous, you know what I mean? ;-)

Comment: :D Thanks. But why bothering with additional wrapper classes and calling methods to get and set the values in there if we have a far more comfortable option where all the synchronizing is done automatically in behind and we don't have any interface change...

Comment: I agree yours is better approach. Like I said, after I posted my first answer, I thought that it could also be done using property. But later I decided not to change my first answer. After all, if I did add the property approach too, you wouldn't have got the chance to post an answer here ;-)

Comment: @ByteCommander Nice answer. It seems a little weird to me. As far as I know, when I write `b.foo`, the getter method must be called. So why I receive the value of variable `self.foo` instead of the dictionary you that you returned in the getter method (i.e. `foo(self)`)?

Comment: @EbraHim `foo` is a property, that means to the outside it acts like an ordinary instance member, same as if I initialized it with `self.foo = 1` anywhere, e.g. in the constructor method. But internally it's a pair of two functions, one getter and one setter that get implicitly called when you access the property. The `@property | def foo(self):` method is the getter and looks up the value mapped to "foo_key" in the dictionary `foo_dict`. That's where the value is stored. The `@foo.setter | def foo(self, value):` method is the setter, it stores the new `value` in the `foo_dict` with "foo_key".

Comment: I like this approach! I've never used `@property` before. I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: This is a pretty cool way to bundle all the private variables up in a dictionary and effectively let you drop the leading underscore convention on those private variables.  and allow you to set the public property directly in the init like `self.foo=`

Answer (score 4):

> Is this even possible in Python?

**Answer 1**: Not in a straight forward manner, because `int` is immutable. However...

**Answer 2**: There are workarounds for achieving what you want.

Instead of using `int` for your variable `foo`, you need to have a *wrapper* class for `foo`, since `int` is immutable, and any *wrapper* class you define is not.

Your wrapper class for `foo`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.foo = val
    def set(self, val):
        self.foo = val
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.foo)
```

Then, the class where you are having that *consistent variable-dictionary pair* could be something like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo(1)
        self.foo_dict = {
            'foo_key': self.foo
            }
    def set_foo(self, newval):
        self.foo.set(newval)
```

Test run:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo
1
>>> a.foo_dict['foo_key']
1
>>> a.set_foo(20)
>>> a.foo
20
>>> a.foo_dict['foo_key']
20
```

Comment: Why you didn't simply used a single class for that?

Comment: @EbraHim Because two-class is the obvious solution for this case.

Comment: I posted a temporary answer, May I ask you to take a look?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class Test(object):
    def __init__(self,foo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.foo_dict = {'foo_key': foo}
    def set_foo(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.foo_dict['foo_key'] = foo


>>> a = Test(1)
>>> a.foo
1
>>> a.foo_dict
{'foo_key': 1}
>>> a.set_foo(2)
>>> a.foo
2
>>> a.foo_dict
{'foo_key': 2}
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

I did not fully understood your question but if your want to change the value of `self.foo`, you can do it directly using a dictionary. Suppose that you have some dictionary:

```
self.some_dict = {"valueA":1}
```

Considering that a dictionary functions by `key` to `value` pairs, you an change the value of `valueA` like this:

```
self.some_dict["valueA"] = some_value
```

Therefore, the value of the key is changed to `some_value`. As another possibility you can create a copy of a dictionary using `dict.copy`. With this you have another dictionary with the same values of the first, and then update with `dict.update` to add new elements or values in the keys. Something like this:

```
self.some_dict = {"value1":1}
self.other_dict = some_dict
self.other_dict.update("{"value2": 2}")
```

With this you can update the `value2` to other_dict.

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa, slow it dwon wihle you type, will ya! Tehre are too many seplling errors in yuor writing. And I don't tihnk you have understood the questoin well.