# Using Properties in Python classes cause "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class

Here is a test class that I wrote to became familiar with `@properties` and `setter` functionality in Python script:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.x =  value
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self.x = value
```

The problems is that when I want to create an object from my class, I face the following error:

```
>>> t = Test(1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    t = Test(1)
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 3, in __init__
    self.x =  value
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 9, in x
    self.x = value
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 9, in x
  #A bunch of lines skipped
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
>>>
```

Comment: Use `self._x` instead of `self.x` for private member. By naming both member and property `x` property shadows member, and `return self.x` in getter body calls itself.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You are using the same name for the getter, setter and attribute. When setting up a property, you must rename the attribute locally; the convention is to prefix it with an underscore.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._x =  value

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
```

Comment: Thank you. Please take a look at _Byte Commander_'s answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929460/how-to-keep-variable-and-dictionary-that-contains-it-consistent/36930474?noredirect=1#comment61422678_36930474). He used same name for `setter`, `getter` and `variable`, but his program works fine.

Comment: If you've defined the setter method, it's better to only access the private variable `self._x` in the getter / setter / deleter methods. In \_\_init__ you can just say `self.x = value`.

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure that's correct. Why is it better? It's not a convention I'm aware of.

Comment: You are implementing a setter methode for a reason, probably to do some input checking / manipulation. It makes sense to do the same thing during instantiation of the object.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Assigning to the private attribute in `__init__` will bypass the `property` `setter` method and therefore not apply the logic contained there, as @Rob said. It is probably buggy or at least inconsistent to allow potentially different values during instantiation and later one, during re-assignment.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is in these lines:

```
def x(self):
    return self.x
```

Replace it with

```
def get_x(self):
    return self.x
```

Because now the function calls itself, leading to the recursion depth exceeded.

Comment: I want to use `@properties`.

Comment: Using getters/setters is a Python antipattern. It's recommended to uses properties with the @property decorator. Read: https://www.pythonmorsels.com/customizing-what-happens-when-you-assign-attribute/