# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded python property getter setter

Tags: python, properties

I am trying to do getter setter in this simple class,

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def set_name(self, n):
        self.name = n

    name = property(get_name, set_name)


p = Person('Lewis')
p.name = 'Philo'
```

Looks pretty simple and straightforward, but somehow it's not working, what am I missing, help me find what is the understanding that I am going wrong.

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/napoleon/python-play/oops/person.py", line 15, in <module>
    p = Person('Lewis')
  File "/Users/napoleon/python-play/oops/person.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.name = n
  File "/Users/napoleon/python-play/oops/person.py", line 10, in set_name
    self.name = n
  File "/Users/napoleon/python-play/oops/person.py", line 10, in set_name
    self.name = n
  File "/Users/napoleon/python-play/oops/person.py", line 10, in set_name
    self.name = n
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: A more accurate duplicate: [Using Properties in Python classes cause “maximum recursion depth exceeded” (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36931415/6045800)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like since `name` is a property, that you defined with `get_name` and `set_name` when you call `self.name = n` what it does is actually calls the setter of the property, which is `set_name`.

when you initialize the Person object, it calls `__init__` which then calls `set_name` since it has the line `self.name = n`, and the same happens in `set_name` itself (since it has the same line).

a solution may be creating a `_name` member and using it in the getter and setter.

in more complex cases you may check if it's not holding the value you sent to the setter, and only then change the member's value in the setter.

```
class Person:
    _name = None
    def __init__(self, n):
        self._name = n

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def set_name(self, n):
        self._name = n

    name = property(get_name, set_name)
```

Comment: answer is prefered for a verbose explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are making accessors and mutators in Python, you shouldn't use the same tag for the property and attributes, so all you need to do is use the `_` to prevent the infinite loop:

Just replace `self.name` with `self._name` and you should be  good:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def set_name(self, n):
        self._name = n

    name = property(get_name, set_name)

    p = Person('Lewis')
    p.name = 'Philo'
    
    print(p.get_name()) #prints "Philo"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the code in your class is running an infinite loop.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def set_name(self, n):
        self.name = n

    name = property(get_name, set_name)


p = Person('Lewis')
p.name = 'Philo'
```

should be:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def set_name(self, n):
        self._name = n

    name = property(get_name, set_name)


p = Person('Lewis')
p.name = 'Philo'
```

The extra `_` is so that you don't run an infinite loop. See, whenever you set or get the name with your code you provided, it would run the `set_name` or `get_name` forever because you are either setting or getting the name within the getter or setter methods.

For example, with `p.name = 'Philo'`, you are running the setter method. Within the setter method, though, you are calling the setter method again and again with `self.name = n`, and doing `self._name = n` prevents Python from an infinite loop.