# How to feed the address to a class

Tags: python, pointers

For example a class:

```py
s=2

class a:
    def __init__(x):
        a.x=x

t = a(s)
.....
```

What I want is to feed `a` with the address of `x` so when I change the value of `s` then the value of `a.x` can be changed. I know C++ can use pointers to solve this I don't know how I can do it in Python.

Comment: You can't do it in Python. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2065105/3001761 for workarounds

Comment: Why do you have to pass that as an argument, when you want to change it anyway, just use s as a global variable that you directly use in your class? If this was helpful, please respond and I will make an answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, why? Don't the mutable types behave in the desired way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: @Dmitry Exactly. Mutable types are passed around as references, variables aren't.

Comment: `int` objects are immutable, **you cannot change their value**. Python doesn't have pointers, although, everything *acts* as a pointer because everything has reference semantics. Assignment to a variable merely makes that name refer to another object.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, that is not very necessary. Python is a high-level language which handle the memory with garbage collector, therefore you are giving up some control and speed for convenience.
Everything in python acts like the reference type in C++. Basically, 5 is an object, and 's' is a reference variable pointing to that object. So, when you pass 's' as parameter, actually the object '5' is taken. Now you change 's' value simply means you let 's' points to another object ('6', for exp)
To achieve the use as a pointer, you may use int as a reference type by creating

```
class Int:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class a:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

s = Int(5)
t = a(s)

s.value = 6  # s is the same object but has a different value
print(t.x.value)  # it should be 6 instead of 5
```