# Could someone help me here? Python object maintaining between separate functions

Tags: python, oop, scope

I wrote this simple python program to help me with a bug in another program. It clearly illustrates the problem.

```
import copy

class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def one(o):
    print("1: o.name:", o.name) # "foo"
    obackup = copy.deepcopy(o) 
    o.name = "bar"
    print("2: o.name:", o.name) # "bar"
    print("3: obackup.name:", obackup.name) # "foo"
    o = obackup
    print("4: o.name:", o.name) # "foo"

def two(o):
    print("5: o.name:", o.name) # "bar"!

def main():
    o = Obj("foo")
    one(o)
    two(o)

main()
```

My guess is that `o` is being overwritten somehow as a local variable to the function `one()`. But I have no idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`o` is a local variable to the `one()` so this problem cannot be fixed elegantly. But you could use some
reference/pointer which you pass to the `one()` and `two()`.

[Simulating Pointers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145722/simulating-pointers-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know that there is no easy fix. I've fixed it now by having all relevant functions return the object.

Comment: It would be much better to restructure the code (as mentioned, returning the object works well) than to try to simulate pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Forget that the `copy` module exists, it almost never is needed and often produces surprising results.

As soon as you say `o = obackup` in `one()` you have created a new binding for the formal argument which then goes out of scope after `print('4...`