# Passing a set of NumPy arrays into C function for input and output

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes, ffi

Let's assume we have a C function that takes a set of one or more input arrays, processes them, and writes its output into a set of output arrays. The signature looks as follows (with `count` representing the number of array elements to be processed):

```c
void compute (int count, float** input, float** output)
```

I want to call this function from Python via ctypes and use it to apply a transformation to a set of NumPy arrays. For a one-input/one-output function defined as

```c
void compute (int count, float* input, float* output)
```

the following works:

```python
import ctypes
import numpy

from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./block.so')
fun = lib.compute
fun.restype = None
fun.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int,
                ndpointer(ctypes.c_float),
                ndpointer(ctypes.c_float)]

data = numpy.ones(1000).astype(numpy.float32)
output = numpy.zeros(1000).astype(numpy.float32)
fun(1000, data, output)
```

However, I have no clue how to create the corresponding pointer array for *multiple* inputs (and/or outputs). Any ideas?

**Edit**: So people have been wondering how `compute` knows how many array pointers to expect (as `count` refers to the number of elements per array). This is, in fact, hard-coded; a given `compute` knows precisely how many inputs and outputs to expect. It's the caller's job to verify that `input` and `output` point to the right number of inputs and outputs. Here's an example `compute` taking 2 inputs and writing to 1 output array:

```
virtual void compute (int count, float** input, float** output) {
    float* input0 = input[0];
    float* input1 = input[1];
    float* output0 = output[0];
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        float fTemp0 = (float)input1[i];
        fRec0[0] = ((0.09090909090909091f * fTemp0) + (0.9090909090909091f * fRec0[1]));
        float fTemp1 = (float)input0[i];
        fRec1[0] = ((0.09090909090909091f * fTemp1) + (0.9090909090909091f * fRec1[1]));
        output0[i] = (float)((fTemp0 * fRec1[0]) - (fTemp1 * fRec0[0]));
        // post processing
        fRec1[1] = fRec1[0];
        fRec0[1] = fRec0[0];
    }
}
```

I have no way of influencing the signature and implementation of `compute`. I can verify (from Python!) how many inputs and outputs are required. Key problem is how to give the correct `argtypes` for the function, and how to produce appropriate data structures in NumPy (an array of pointers to NumPy arrays).

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145722/simulating-pointers-in-python) help at all?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no. It's more specific to NumPy and ctypes. Nonetheless, thank you.

Comment: Probably you'll need to rewrite `compute` to store the data flat.

Comment: The `compute` function is auto-generated, so I have very little influence as far as signature and implementation go.

Comment: How do you know in the autogenerated function, how many arrays were inserted?

Comment: If numpy can't cope with it, you'll need a C wrapper that has the signature you've solved already. Involves copying input and output arrays. Viable?

Comment: Can you post C code for `void compute (int count, float** input, float** output)` or C code that uses this `compute`?

Comment: +1 because array(float) to pointer(float) conversion is not obvious/trivial in ctypes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this specifically with Numpy arrays, you could use:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes

count = 5
size = 1000

#create some arrays
arrays = [np.arange(size,dtype="float32") for ii in range(count)] 

#get ctypes handles
ctypes_arrays = [np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(array) for array in arrays]

#Pack into pointer array
pointer_ar = (ctypes.POINTER(C.c_float) * count)(*ctypes_arrays)

ctypes.CDLL("./libfoo.so").foo(ctypes.c_int(count), pointer_ar, ctypes.c_int(size))
```

Where the C side of things might look like:

```
# function to multiply all arrays by 2
void foo(int count, float** array, int size)
{
   int ii,jj;
   for (ii=0;ii<count;ii++){
      for (jj=0;jj<size;jj++)
         array[ii][jj] *= 2;    
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C, `float**` points to first element in a table/array of `float*` pointers.

Presumably each of those `float*` points to first element in a table/array of `float` values.

Your function declaration has 1 count, however it's not clear what this count applies to:

```
void compute (int count, float** input, float** output)
```

- 2D matrix `count` x `count` in size?
- `count` -sized array of `float*` each somehow terminated, e.g. with `nan`?
- null-terminated array of `float*` each of `count` elements (reasonable assumption)?

Please clarify your question and I will clarify my answer :-)

Assuming the last API interpretation, here's my sample compute function:

```
/* null-terminated array of float*, each points to count-sized array
*/
extern void compute(int count, float** in, float** out)
{
    while (*in)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            (*out)[i] = (*in)[i]*42;
        }
        in++; out++;
    }
}
```

Test code for the sample compute function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void compute(int count, float** in, float** out);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
#define COUNT 3
    float ina[COUNT] = { 1.5, 0.5, 3.0 };
    float inb[COUNT] = { 0.1, -0.2, -10.0 };
    float outa[COUNT];
    float outb[COUNT];
    float* in[] = {ina, inb, (float*)0};
    float* out[] = {outa, outb, (float*)0};

    compute(COUNT, in, out);

    for (int row=0; row<2; row++)
        for (int c=0; c<COUNT; c++)
            printf("%d %d %f %f\n", row, c, in[row][c], out[row][c]);
    return 0;
}
```

And how you use same via ctypes in Python for `count` == 10 `float` subarrays and size `2` `float*` array, containing 1 real subarray and NULL terminator:

```
import ctypes

innertype = ctypes.ARRAY(ctypes.c_float, 10)
outertype = ctypes.ARRAY(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float), 2)

in1 = innertype(*range(10))
in_ = outertype(in1, None)
out1 = innertype(*range(10))
out = outertype(out1, None)

ctypes.CDLL("./compute.so").compute(10, in_, out)

for i in range(10): print in_[0][i], out[0][i]
```

Numpy interface to ctypes is covered here http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Ctypes#head-4ee0c35d45f89ef959a7d77b94c1c973101a562f, arr.ctypes.shape[:] arr.ctypes.strides[:] and arr.ctypes.data are what you need; you might be able to feed that directly to your `compute`.

Here's an example:

```
In [55]: a = numpy.array([[0.0]*10]*2, dtype=numpy.float32)

In [56]: ctypes.cast(a.ctypes.data, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))[0]
Out[56]: 0.0

In [57]: ctypes.cast(a.ctypes.data, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))[0] = 1234

In [58]: a
Out[58]: 
array([[ 1234.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
            0.,     0.],
       [    0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
            0.,     0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: This looks great. Your interpretation is, of course, quite correct: `count` refers to the number of elements in the `float*` "array". The number of pointers that `float**` encompasses is known at generation time of `compute`, so `compute` "knows" how many inputs and outputs to expect. (It's generated by compiling another language.) Hence, no null termination required. I'll amend the question.

Comment: ebarr's specific hint did the trick; nonetheless, thanks a lot for your in-depth explanation that helped clarify the issue and taught me quite a bit about interfacing...