# Link a name to another name

Tags: python, reference

I have the following code:

```
class B:

    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

class A:

    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.b = B(self.msg)

    def update(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

a = A('hello')

print a.msg
print a.b.msg

a.update('bye')

print a.msg
print a.b.msg
```

Which prints:

```
hello
hello
bye
hello
```

This is not what I want. What I need is that `a.b.msg` is "linked" to `a.msg`: `a.b.msg` must always refer to the same object as `a.msg`, even after rebinding `a.msg`.  Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Do they have to be strings?

Comment: Add `self.b.msg = msg` in the `update` method?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: this is what I want to avoid. I want that to happen automagically, not forcing it by hand. The background is that I can have lots of sub-objects using the parent's data, as cached properties, which I can not even enumerate.

Comment: @wnnmaw: they *can* be strings, but can also be other things. The solution should support any kind of object

Comment: strings are immutable. Just use a mutable object to store the message and then mutate it.

Comment: I want all references to be linked, so that updating one reference updates all references. I do not want to update the object that the references are referring to: I am going to use new objects when updating. This is not a matter of mutable or immutable, since I am not going to mutate any object.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem is, that you want a behaviour similar to a call by reference in C++. To achieve this, what you could do is to work with a little hack to emulate a memory location. [Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145722/simulating-pointers-in-python) The reason for that to work is found in [this questions accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference), it is related to Pythons mutable and immutable objects.

```
class ref:
    def __init__(self, obj): self.obj = obj
    def get(self):    return self.obj
    def set(self, obj):      self.obj = obj

class B:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

class A:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = ref(msg)
        self.b = B(self.msg)

    def update(self, msg):
        self.msg.set(msg)

a = A('hello')

print a.msg.get() #hello
print a.b.msg.get() #hello

a.update('bye')

print a.msg.get() #bye
print a.b.msg.get() #bye
```

If however this means too many changes to your code, what you could also do is to define a method `msg(self)` in every function with a `msg`, renaming `msg` to `message` or whatever.
That way you would get the String by calling `a.msg()` for example, which would represent less change to your existing code. But I fear that there is no way of solving your problem without any change to your code.

Sample two, with a `msg()` method:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.message = msg

    def msg(self):
        return self.message.get()

class A:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.message = ref(msg)
        self.b = B(self.message)

    def update(self, msg):
        self.message.set(msg)

    def msg(self):
        return self.message.get()

a = A('hello')

print a.msg() #hello
print a.b.msg() #hello
```

A third solution I see would be to use a `List` instead of a reference class:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

class A:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = [msg]
        self.b = B(self.msg)

    def update(self, msg):
        self.msg[0] = msg

a = A('hello')

print a.msg[0] #hello
print a.b.msg[0] #hello

a.update('bye')

print a.msg[0] #bye
print a.b.msg[0] #bye
```

In general you could use any other mutable object for this purpose, but take care of being aware that you can not **reassign** the mutable Object in some "child Class" like `B` is in your example.

Comment: This is interesting, but having to add the `.get()` means lots of changes to my code

Comment: @jeckyll2hide sorry, that's the best idea that came to my mind... I'll update if I find a better, easier to use way!

Answer (score 1):

Why can't `b` keep track of `a` and use `a.msg` to get its `msg`?

```
class MockA:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

class B:

    def __init__(self, a):
        if isinstance(a, A):
            self._a = a
        else:
            self._a = MockA(a)

    @property
    def msg(self):
        return self._a.msg

class A:

    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.b = B(self)

    def update(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

a = A('hello')

print a.msg
print a.b.msg

a.update('bye')

print a.msg
print a.b.msg

b = B('here')

print b.msg
```

Prints:

```
hello
hello
bye
bye
here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a property:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, msg):
    self.b = B(msg)

  @property
  def msg(self):
    return self.b.msg

  @property.setter
  def msg(self, value):
    self.b.msg = value
```

I have this a little backwards compared to what you want.  Here I always link `a.msg` to `a.b.msg` instead of the other way around, but it's really mostly semantics at that point.  The changes should appear to propagate both directions so there should be little practical difference.

Comment: I do not want to update self.b.msg: there is also self.c.msg, ..., an indeterminate number: the objects themselves are cached properties, which I can not enumerate.