# Replace contents of a list passed as an argument

Tags: python

I'm trying to write code that does this:

```
the_list = ['some list', 0, 1, 2]

def change(l):
    x = ['some other list', 3, 4, 5]
    l <- x

change(the_list)
print(the_list)    # ['some other list', 3, 4, 5]
```

I.e. replacing the contents of list `l` with the contents of `x`.
What is the most pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do following to replace the contents of `l` within the function `change`:

```
def change(l):
    x = ['some other list', 3, 4, 5]
    l[:] = x
```

This will replace the slice range (in this case the whole list) with contents of given iterable.

Comment: Just be careful with aliases. If you have `list1 = ['some list']` and `list2 = list1`, running `change(list1)` will change both `list1` and `list2`. You can avoid this by instead setting `list2 = list1[:]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you can't have pointers in Python. So assignment of the new object to your argument variable doesn't change the value in the outer scope. But you could do it with an object with explicit **get** and **set** methods. I borrowed the code from [Simulating Pointers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145722/simulating-pointers-in-python). See also [Pointers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106689/pointers-in-python) for further discussion.

```
class ref:
    def __init__(self, obj): self.obj = obj
    def get(self):    return self.obj
    def set(self, obj):      self.obj = obj

def change(l):
    x = ['some other list', 3, 4, 5]
    l.set(x)

the_list=ref(['some list', 0, 1, 2])
change(the_list)
print(the_list.get())
```

and because you can explicitly set a list by `l[:]=x`, as mentioned in **niemmi** answer, you can do it that way too.

Answer (score -2):

The outer scope should already be accessible to the function as python will look locally then move up in the scope till it finds a variable name or errors.

So you should be able to do this.

```
the_list = ['some list', 0, 1, 2]

def change():
    x = ['some other list', 3, 4, 5]
    for item in x:
        the_list.append(item)

change()
print(the_list)
```

Added output

```
['some list', 0, 1, 2, 'some other list', 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid appends, as these are performance monsters.  
Also, it was about overwriting contents of the list, not appending to it

Comment: you can avoid the append if you wish, the point is the outer scope is available to you to do with as you wish, and you can use and it and it will change globally.

Comment: The outer scope is almost _never_ available. It's only available if the function is nested and called right after definition, or the list is defined globally.