# Multiple names refer to 1 value issue

Tags: python, list

I have read this link recently [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)
and it raises a question. The author only said about this

```
x = 23
y = x
```

But what about this

```
x = 23
y = 23
```

Is it still right that both x and y refer to one value 23 ? the first “23” is the same as the second “23” ? If it is then why I try this

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]
b.reverse()
print(a)
```

The result is

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Why is that? because both a and b refer to value [1,2,3] and list is a mutable type. As the author said 
    "if two names refer to the same value, and the value is mutated, then both names see the change" In my code, b changed, why a didn't

Comment: I think you're confusing with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145722/simulating-pointers-in-python) behaviour

Comment: Integers are immutable, for a start. There's also a cache of integers so their `id` will compare equal for small numbers. I can't properly understand what part you're confused about.

Comment: @roganjosh yeah i khow intergers are immutable, but what about the list, why a didn't change

Comment: Why would `a` change? Just because `a` and `b` happen to be lists with the same values does not make them share an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a brand new `list` twice does not create an aliasing situation. Creating *any* mutable type twice, from scratch, will not cause aliasing. Your `a` and `b` have the same contents, but they are two completely different `list`s.

The CPython reference interpreter *will* occasionally cache small/simple *immutable* types (small `int`s, the empty `tuple` and `str`, etc.) so you would find that anything initialized to `23` is initialized to the *same* `23`, but that's an implementation detail that rarely matters in practice. Basically, as long as you don't assign to one name from an already *existing* object (and don't do the trickier stuff like sequence multiplication or mutable default arguments), aliasing doesn't occur in any dangerous sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you explain more, why it does not creat an aliasing situation since both refer to 1 mutable value

Comment: @JuniorCoder: They don't. Each time you type `[1, 2, 3]` it makes a *new* mutable value. `a = [1, 2, 3]` followed by `b = a` would make both names alias the same mutable value, but otherwise, *all* freshly typed literals are logically distinct (even if, as noted, some immutable literals are actually the same, as a performance optimization).